# Using strtotime and date to add time to date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am having an incredibly hard time understanding strtotime even after reading the never ending questions on stack overflow on the subject....

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+3 months",date('Y-m-d')))
```

Why does that not return `2013-10-09` (given today's date is `2013-07-09`)

Instead it returns `1970-03-31` 3 months after the PHP default date.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php -- Date is for formatting a timestamp. If you want to get the current timestamp, use `time()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) expects the second argument to be numeric:

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+3 months", time()))
```

or even

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+3 months"))
```

PS: you could find it out yourself if used `error_reporting` level that includes `E_NOTICE` and checked your logs.

It's actually a good idea to have `display_errors` turned on on your development server with `error_reporting` at least of `E_ALL`. As a developer you want to be the first person to see your mistakes, don't you?

Comment: So i'm taking string "+3 months" and adding to to time() in date('Y-m-d') format......correct?

Comment: @Hydra IO: You're taking `time()` adding `+3 months` to it and format the result timestamp using `date`

Comment: correct, btw, you can use both singular and plural for period, so "+3 month" would work as well

Comment: Thank you very much, as soon as the pesky 10 minute limit is up, I can mark as solved =D